# Implement Candy Crush like level graph

Tags: unity, opengl, android, graphics

I want to implement road-map like level graph where in you can see what level are you and your friends are on. Just like we see in Candy Crush Saga.For people who have not seen Candy Crush Saga, please see the image below for your reference.

[image]

I want to understand the technology I should be using here. `libgdx` is one option i keep hearing is best for Android gaming engine. But somehow I feel `Unity for Android` would provide more bang performance wise.

This is my first try at gaming, please help me understand my options.

Comment: Assume some of us have never seen and never planned to see Candy Crush and that we have no idea what you're talking about without a picture or something to show us.

Comment: @Sean thanks for your inputs. I have added an illustration for your reference.

Comment: **FIRST** - opinion based question are not really a suitable fit for this site and questions about getting started / which tech are also not welcome. So this will be closed. Now, some advice only because you're new... You could write this in just about anything, from JavaScript to Flash to Unity to libgdx. Frankly I would just do it in **JavaScript** because iteration times are really fast and it's write once, run everywhere (WORA), including Android, _provided that_ you test it contantly on an Android device during development. If you want it to run on really old phones, use libgdx or Unity.